# Not getting output from python script when run through PHP

Tags: php, python, permissions, windows-10

I have a python script that prints out the program names that are currently in the volume mixer in Windows 10.

This works fine when I run it in the cmd.

```
C:\wamp\www\Volume>py test.py
firefox.exe,Spotify.exe,Microsoft.Photos.exe,Steam.exe,
```

and here is my python script.

```
import sys
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities


def main():
list = ''
sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
for session in sessions:
    volume = session.SimpleAudioVolume
    if session.Process and session.Process.name():
        list += session.Process.name() + ','

sys.stdout.write(list)       


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And my PHP:

```
$python = "py";
$script = "test.py";
exec("$python $script 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

But when I run it in PHP using WAMP, I don't get any output from that script, nothing is outputted.

If I change my python script to only contain "print("TESTING")" then I can read that output fine in PHP which makes me think that my python code is failing perhaps due to permissions. So I changed the user from SYSTEM to my own user so when I use:

```
echo exec("whoami") // Outputs my user account name
```

I thought maybe my PHP script was off, so I tried running it though the command line, but the results are what I want:

```
C:\wamp\www\Volume>php index.php
Array
(
[0] => firefox.exe,Spotify.exe,Microsoft.Photos.exe,Steam.exe,
)
```

So I'm at a loss as to why when I execute my PHP code through my browser, I am not getting any output unless my python script only contains :

```
print("TESTING")
```

What could possibly be going wrong?

**EDIT**
So I decided to debug this further by altering my python script to create a .txt file on my desktop, this works fine when running it through the command line. But again, when I run it through my browser/PHP, that file isn't created. So maybe I need to grant special permissions to my python script? I'm not sure why I need to do that though as I have given PHP my user account

Comment: `sys.stdout.flush()` is always nice to do. It's implied, but for debugging purposes it's always sweet to have it there. Also adding a `os.exit(1)` could be useful, just to make sure you're exiting with a good exit code - so PHP doesn't try to garbage the output or anything. Again, just for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Torxed I tried what you suggested and I'm getting the same results :/ Oddly enough though I made a mistake when making these changes and I got the error back

Comment: To me, a novice newbie - It's strange that you would get **any** result using `php index.php` but not when running through the web browser, especially in Windows. If anything your WAMP server should have more permissions since (if i'm not mistaken) WAMP runs as a service user under Windows.

Comment: What does your apache error log say? Anything at all? Could you add a `print("Just something");` to your `index.php` just to make sure there's output from it at all? pref one at the start and one at the bottom to see how far the execution gets.

Comment: @Torxed Yeah it is strange, I actually changed the user type WAMP runs as under to my own account instead of service but I get the exact same results. 
My apache error log doesn't say a thing! 
Yeah my index.php is fine and can output things fine too :/

Comment: I'd say this is a environment variable thing. What does `<?php print_r(getenv("PATH")); ?>` output? In both your execution scenarios.

Comment: Good point.
They both output a bunch of stuff, in the command line cygwin is mentioned a lot, but not when I do the same in my browser

Comment: You never mentioned Cygwin earlier.. Where did Cygwin come in to the picture? You're running WAMP, right? And you're not using Cygwin here in this project at all right?

Comment: @Torxed Sorry, I haven't used cygwin in months so I completely forgot about it. And yes you're correct.
I think it is down to the environment for python perhaps, what I'm trying to do at the moment is use "/runas" in windows and "/env" to try and copy my user enviro

Comment: You could try and just use absolute paths. Because if you're running this from a terminal, your user will have all the nessecities in the `PATH` env variable. Where as a system "user" most likely won't. So try `$python = "C:\\Python3.5\\python.exe";` for instance.

Comment: @Torxed I originally tried that - I should of mentioned

Comment: Not a problem, it's almost impossible to remember all the things you've tried :) Did you also try a absolute path for the python script itself? And not just the python executable?

Comment: Humm, maybe I've just drained my IQ for this evening.. but.. `AudioUtilities` - Wouldn't that utilize the current users access to audio sources? I'd bet money on the fact that `services` user has no audio sources active in it's context.. Maybe that's why you get output when you run it as your user?

Comment: @Torxed Yeah I've tried absolute paths for python and the script.

I think you may be on to something there! I just tried to output memory usage etc. to see if it could do stuff and it can! I think that you're correct that the services user has no audio sources. It's strange though because like I said before when I type exec("whoami") it outputs my username

Comment: I'm running Linux on all my travel gear and I'm away on holiday so I don't have access to a Windows machine, so I can't debug this further for you I think. Voting up this in hopes that someone else gets curious. It's a good question also so I'll keep an eye on it. Best of luck :)

Comment: @Torxed You're on holiday? Get off the internet then! Thanks. I'm going to update my question with an answer as I think you're right. I may make another question.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found out why I'm not getting any output from my python script, thanks to @Torxed.

It seems like when I run the Python script through WAMP/PHP it must run as a different user/environment which doesn't have any Audio.

This is odd however as I've set 'wampapache64' to run as my user account, even after a restart I'm still getting the same results.

I've even tried

```
runas /savecred /noprofile /user:<USER>
```

But that just returns the password prompt which I won't be able to fill out in PHP.

This project looks like a dead end for now.